# How to manage payment after splitting order in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, payment, payment-gateway, order-splitting

I am having schenario where I need to split order on seller basis. Let's say if customer adds 10 products in a cart which are from 3 different seller A, B, C  out of these 3 are from seller A, 3 from seller B and 4 from seller C in that case I create 3 orders which is working till now.

Now my question is how to manage payment if I am using any online payment gateway systems.

As we need to store transaction Id for these order which we need in case of refund.

Can any one please tell me the correct approach? Is it possible?

Comment: How can we split orders by using third-party payment gateway?(like PayPal)

Comment: stuck in the same situation, have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally: You should split the orders before they are processed, so that each one is invoiced separately and gets its own transaction ID. From a payment flow perspective, this would be similar to how the multi-shipping checkout works.

Comment: I am splitting order before processed but at the end we need to send only one order to gateway. Am I correct?